# Using sort() first to sort a simple number array, then filter() to get numbers greater than 25. But output isn't sorted correctly. Why?

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie to JavaScript. Just created this simple number array. I then sorted this array and filtered numbers that are greater than 25.

Output of numarray = **[100, 25, 28, 32, 97]**

Why is 100 the first number? Shouldn't 100 be the last number?

```
let numArray = [9, 32, 25, 1, 0, -10, -100, 100, 28, 97, 3];

numArray.sort();

console.log(numArray.filter(function(numbers){
    return numbers >= 25;
}));
```

Comment: The default for `.sort()` is to compare values as **strings**.

Comment: What function would you recommend then? Sorry, don't know much as I just started learning JS.

Comment: numbers.sort((a, b) => a - b);
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: [You have to pass in a small comparator function.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Thank you so much! Stack Overflow is truly an amazing place. You guys are so helpful! :)